# Returning Value based on multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to return a specific value that meets all criteria.

The formula I tried but doesn't work at all is :

```
=INDEX(E10:E24, MATCH(A2, A10:A24& MATCH(C2,C10:C24, 0)))
```

In Cell D2 I would like   to retrieve the score found in the EXAMPLE DB when A2 and C2 match in the EXAMPLE DB. The result in this example should display "7" from the Example DB.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FILTER` instead:

```
=FILTER(E10:E24,(A10:A24=A2)*(C10:C24=C2))
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

**only first instance match**

```js
=xlookup(A2&C2,index(A10:A24&C10:C24),E10:E24,)
```

**useful if there are multiple matches for `Jul 3 + Texas Rangers`**

```js
=filter(E10:E24,A10:A24=A2,C10:C24=C2)
```